# AsyncHttpClient is not sending requests

Tags: java, android, asynchttpclient

I have an app that sends POST requests to a server,
it's implemented as follows:

```
AsyncHttpClient myClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("key", "value");
params.put("more", "data");
myClient.post("http://site/post.php", params, new 
TextHttpResponseHandler() {
//@override and stuff.....
});
```

everything works but when it comes to

```
myClient.get("http://site/post.php", params, new 
TextHttpResponseHandler() {
//@override and stuff.....
});
```

it stops working.

What could possibly be the answer to this?

NOTE: I tried HttpPost and other libraries but none of them successfully sent a post request. My Android version is 6.0.

Comment: Can you share the logcat output?

Comment: my phone is not rooted, i can't run logcat

Comment: You can still share the logcat using Android Studio